# Change file contents with custom data using command line

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, rename

I have many folders and files in it(recursive depth ~2 subdirs) and want to change content of all those files with contents of my single file, keeping original file names in those directories. Are there is batch solution?
Sorry for my French..

Comment: what _French_ do you mean? Can you explain the content story more precisely?

Comment: Please describe the contents of the file, and how you want the files to be renamed.

Comment: about "French": is just a joke =) i am weak in English so hard to explain what i mean. anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with "change content of all those files with contents of my single file, keeping original file names" do you mean "copy my single file over all those files keeping original file names", then this Batch file do that:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Parent\folder\to\process" %%a in (*.*) do copy /Y "C:\Data\My Single File.ext" "%%a"
```